# How to use element ref inside useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an HTML element, `nav` which has a ref set in it, `sideNavRef`.

I also want to get a variable to control the animations of that element and for that, I'm doing this:

```js
  const sideNavAnimation = useMemo(() => {
    if (sideNavRef.current) {
      const animations = createSideNavKeyframes({
        startingWidth: (7 * document.body.offsetWidth) / 100,
        endingWidth: 55,
      });
      const animation = sideNavRef.current.animate(animations.animation);
      animation.pause();
      return animation;
    }
  }, []);
```

The `createSideNavKeyframes` returns a keyframes array with calculated easing values for each step (0.1 to 1).

The easing function is this:

```js
function easeInOutQuart(x: number): number {
  return x < 0.5 ? 8 * x * x * x * x : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * x + 2, 4) / 2;
}
```

Since it would need to calculate this on every render I chose to use a memoized value since it wouldn't change.

But since the dependecy array is empty, it means that in the first render the value for the ref is still undefined and so the animations will be undefined as well.

Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: Hi LoyalPotato, did you check my answer?

Comment: I did, I just wanted to know if there were other options as well, before accepting

Comment: I see LoyalPotato :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is registered with `sideNavRef.current` still not defined because `useMemo` runs before the component renders. You could add `sideNavRef.current` in the dependency array, to ask `useMemo` to create a new version of your function, but for that, your component should re-render somehow, cause `sideNavRef.current` changing won't trigger a `re-render` and `useMemo` check its dependency only on renders.

You could use a state called `componentRendred` for example, add it in the dependency array, and change its value in a `useEffect`, like so:

```js
const [componentRendred, setComponentRendred] = useState(false);
```

```js
 const sideNavAnimation = useMemo(() => {
    if (sideNavRef.current) {
      const animations = createSideNavKeyframes({
        startingWidth: (7 * document.body.offsetWidth) / 100,
        endingWidth: 55,
      });
      const animation = sideNavRef.current.animate(animations.animation);
      animation.pause();
      return animation;
    }
  }, [componentRendred]);
```

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setComponentRendred(true);
},[])
```